# How to find the event procedure being used in VBA form

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]

How do i find what this Event_Procedure is doing , Totally confused 
This came when i right clicked in On Current

**Please help**

Answer (score 3):

instead of right clicking, click on the ellipsis next to it

[image: ellipsis circled]

Comment: Me!GLHCode Any idea how can i find this GLHCode in my form its being used everywhere but i cant find it in my design view

Comment: with an `!`, it refers to the table that's attached to the form - it will take that value from the `GLHCode` field of the current record

Comment: Thats the main issue how do i do it in c# , how do i retrieve the current record after insertion of one

Comment: @vini If you want to get the id of a record inserted against a connection, use @@identity. Your question does not mention this issue.